# Iphone SQLite problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I'm developing an iphone application that read data through the sqlite.
I created a database through Terminal and added to the Xcode project.

I went back to the terminal and includes a new table in the file. sql. The problem is because my new queries do not see the new tables. This is kind a cache? How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Where is the SQLite file? Is it in your application bundle? Make sure you modify the version that's been copied to your iPhone Simulator folder (`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/`) if you’re trying to modify the version running in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I removed the file that was inside the directory of the iPhone Simulator and rerun the application. It worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What code do you use to create the database? Are you checking to see if it exists before copying it to your documents folder? If so, it exists and won't be copied.

Answer (score 0):

You might try uninstalling your app from the simulator (or device) and reinstalling the app presumably with the new SQLite database.  There's a few ways to get the old database in this situation.